# Getting width and height of an image in Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

How do you get width and height of an image imported into pygame. I got the size using:
    Surface.get_size
, but I dont know how to get the width and height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 methods available for getting the width and height of a surface.

The first one is `get_size()`, it returns a tuple `(width,height)`. To access width for instance, you would do: `surface.get_size()[0]` and for height `surface.get_size()[1]`.

The second method is to use `get_width()`, and `get_height()`, which return the width and the height.

I suggest going through the python tutorial, to learn more about basic data structures such as tuples.